# How to add picture in Initializer.cs C#

Tags: c#

```
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
{
    new Vehicle
    {
        OwnerrName="Aleks",
        RegistrationDate=DateTime.Today,
        Color="blue",
        VehicleCategory="golf",
        **?Picture?**,
        Name="golf"
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide more context? What exactly are you trying to use this list for?

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to ask a proper question, everybody will jump on you otherwise :).  Your code has to be indented and properly presented / testable (Ctrl+K to make indented on selection) and you should add a good explanation of what is your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, if I get it you need an `Image` object? Then you can add an `Image` property in your `Vehicle` class, and then in your object instantiation:

```
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
{
    new Vehicle
    {
        OwnerrName="Aleks",
        RegistrationDate=DateTime.Today,
        Color="blue",
        VehicleCategory="golf",
        ImageObject=Image.FromFile("img.jpg"), //Here you load your image
        Name="golf"
    }
};
```

You can change path of your image to find it.